# How to start a new activity from a broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I have a BroadcastReceiver like this

```
    public class OnAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = ComponentInfo.class.getCanonicalName(); 


@Override   
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Received wake up from alarm manager.");

    long rowid = intent.getExtras().getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);

    WakeReminderIntentService.acquireStaticLock(context);
```

I wanted to start a new activity from this. How can it be done? I tried using startActivty(). But that didn't worked. Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your onRecieve method:

```
Intent activityToLaunch = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class); 
Context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public class OnAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  private static final String TAG = ComponentInfo.class.getCanonicalName(); 

 @Override   
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 Log.d(TAG, "Received wake up from alarm manager.");r

 long rowid = intent.getExtras().getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);

 WakeReminderIntentService.acquireStaticLock(context);

 Intent yourActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),your.class);
 startActivity(youActivity);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response . When I tried this , I got an error message to create a method getbasecontext. I am new to android . please help